# Sympy : order of solutions from solve

Tags: sympy, solver

Are solutions from sympy solve() being ordered in some way? Is it from minimal to maximal solutions?
How can I enforce non-negativity of the solution?

In my problem I need unique minimal positive solution. I appreciate all the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They aren't ordered, although if they are numeric you can use `sorted` on them (this will fail if they are symbolic or nonreal). You can force positive only solutions by setting the symbol you solve for as positive, like

```
x = symbols('x', positive=True)
```

Also note the caveat with `sympy.solve` that it is no way guarantees that it has given you all the solutions to an equation---only those which it was able to find with the algorithms that are implemented.

Comment: Setting the symbol one solves for as positive isn't always enough, is it? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50476889/how-to-eliminate-negative-solutions-from-sympy-solve-result