# How to eliminate negative solutions from `sympy.solve` result?

Tags: python, sympy, scientific-computing

How can I make `sympy.solve` not return negative solutions?

This seems to be a different task than adding a constraint like `positive=True` to the symbol I'm solving for. While

```
import sympy

x = sympy.symbols("x")
print(sympy.solve(x**2-4, x))

x = sympy.symbols("x", positive=True)
print(sympy.solve(x**2-4, x))
```

prints

```
[-2, 2]
[2]
```

as expected - I still get a negative solve result for `omega` with

```
import sympy

omega, omega_0, gamma = sympy.symbols("omega, omega_0, gamma", real=True, positive=True)
zeta = 1/((omega_0**2 - omega**2)**2 + gamma**2*omega**2)

omega_R = sympy.solve(sympy.diff(zeta, omega), omega)
print(omega_R)
```

which returns

```
[-sqrt(2)*sqrt(-gamma**2 + 2*omega_0**2)/2, sqrt(2)*sqrt(-gamma**2 + 2*omega_0**2)/2]
```

even though `-sqrt(2)*sqrt(-gamma**2 + 2*omega_0**2)/2` will never be positive for real and positive symbols `omega_0` and `gamma`.

Alternatively, whats's the best way to eliminate the negative solutions afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

SymPy's assumptions system isn't smart enough to know that `-sqrt(2)*sqrt(-gamma**2 + 2*omega_0**2)/2` cannot be positive give the `real` and `positive` assumptions on `omega_0` and `gamma` (I [opened an issue for it](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/14815)). To be on the safe side, SymPy only filters solutions if it knows they cannot have the given assumptions. If the assumptions system gives `None`, meaning it doesn't know, it includes it anyway. For now your best bet is to just filter this solution manually.