# How to force a set of non-linear equations to produce positive results in Python?

Tags: python, sympy, equation

I'm trying to solve 3 non-linear equations using Sympy's [nsolve](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html#sympy.solvers.solvers.nsolve) in Python and I need only positive results. I tried adding positive=True to each of the Symbols but in the following example, B is still negative:

```
from sympy import *

def solveEquation (x,y,phi):
    A = Symbol('A',positive=True)
    B = Symbol('B',positive=True)
    K = Symbol('K',positive=True)

    eq1 = y[0] - A - B * cos(K * x[0] + phi[0])
    eq2 = y[1] - A - B * cos(K * x[1] + phi[1])
    eq3 = y[2] - A - B * cos(K * x[2] + phi[2])

    results = nsolve((eq1, eq2, eq3), (A, B, K), (1, 1, 1),maxsteps=10000)
    return (results[0],results[1],results[2])

print(solveEquation([100,220,330],[10,25,32],[1,2,3]))
```

And here are the results which B is a negative number:

```
(11.2988936136965, -21.4022916997153, 1.29436821905308)
```

Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: 3 equations with 3 unknowns, not sure there is another solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to eliminate negative solutions from \`sympy.solve\` result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50476889/how-to-eliminate-negative-solutions-from-sympy-solve-result)

Comment: Starting from `(10, 10, 10)` instead of `(1, 1, 1)` gives `(21.3142477747760, 21.3256151419475, 10.0217960671029)`.

Comment: The answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/67115516/1089161 shows a function that you can use to systematically modify your initial guess so you can see how other guesses might affect the solution you obtain.