# Why is sympy nsolve giving me different values than what is graphically shown?

Tags: python, scipy, sympy, ode, nonlinear-functions

I am trying to find the values of parameters that solve a system of differential equations (find when the rates are zero, and the values no longer change). I iterated the system with ODEINT and graphically shown it to see what are the values that each ODE eventually converges to.

The weird part is, NSOLVE is giving me different values than what the graph shows as the final stable point.

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import math
import numpy as np
import sympy as sy
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.signal
from numpy import linalg as LA



a = [0.9, 0.9, 0.9] #maximum uptake rate
b = [2, 2, 2] #half-saturation (concentration of nutrients at half maximum rate)
m = [0.2, 0.2, 0.2] #mortality rate
I = 0.7 #nutrient input
E = 0.3 #nutrient output
r = [0.3] #maximum recycling rate
l = [0] #deforestation rate (biomass loss)
q = [1] #Hill coefficient - ease of decomposition of the matter. This can vary through the season.
s = [0.9] #half-saturation (concentration of dead organic matter (delta*R) at half maximum rate)


"""
setting up a range for iterations of the system for each moment t in time
"""
val = 1000
y0 = 1, 1, 1, 1
trange = np.linspace(0, val, val) #equally spaced elements


def system(y, t, a, b, m, I, E, r, l, q, s):
    
    N, R, H, P = y
    dydt = [I - E*N + (r[0]*(m[0]*R)**q[0])/(s[0]**q[0]+(m[0]*R)**q[0]) - a[0]*N*R/(b[0] + N),
            
            a[0]*N*R/(b[0] + N) - m[0]*R - l[0]*R - a[1]*H*R/(b[1] + R),
            
            a[1]*H*R/(b[1] + R) - m[1]*H - a[1]*H*P/(b[2] + H),
            
            a[1]*H*P/(b[2] + H) - m[2]*P]
    
    return dydt



solved = odeint(system, y0, trange, args = (a, b, m, I, E, r, l, q, s), atol = 1.49012e-10)



N = solved[val-1,0]
R = solved[val-1,1]
H = solved[val-1,2]
P = solved[val-1,3]


print(N, R, H, P)
```

returns 1.5119062213983654 0.7448846250807435 0.5724768913289174 0.1295697618640645, which makes sense! Here's the ODE iterated through time:

[image]

```
N, R, H, P = sy.symbols("N R H P")




equilibrium_values = (sy.nsolve([I - E*N + (r[0]*(m[0]*R)**q[0])/(s[0]**q[0]+(m[0]*R)**q[0]) - a[0]*N*R/(b[0] + N),
            
            a[0]*N*R/(b[0] + N) - m[0]*R - l[0]*R - a[1]*H*R/(b[1] + R),
            
            a[1]*H*R/(b[1] + R) - m[1]*H - a[1]*H*P/(b[2] + H),
            
            a[1]*H*P/(b[2] + H) - m[2]*P],(N, R, H, P),(1,1, 1, 1)) )

print(equilibrium_values)
```

and equilibrium_values returns:

Matrix([[1.66676383218065], [0.571428571428325], [0.597439764807860], [-1.76967713603266e-13]])

Which are not the graphically found equilibrium values, which should be the result of solving the system of equations... Anyone has a clue why? Is it an issue with my Python, or have I misunderstood the math behind it?

Comment: What happens if you use the numerical solver `scipy.optimize.fsolve` with the found equilibrium as initial point?

Answer (score 0):

Nonlinear systems are notorious for their sensitivity to initial guesses when using a numeric solver. In this case you have done nothing wrong. If you use initial guesses closer to what you see on the screen you might get a solution where P does not go to zero:

```
guess N,R,H,P= (1.5, 0.7, 0.6, 0.1)
N = 1.50905265512538
R = 0.749587544253425
H = 0.571428571428571
P = 0.129589598408824

guess N,R,H,P= (1.51, 0.7, 0.6, 0.1)
N = 1.66676383218043
R = 0.571428571428571
H = 0.597439764807826
P = -1.21722045507780e-18
```

In cases like these it is nice to be able to make a systematic tweaking of the input variables. For that, something like `tweak` shown below can be used:

```
def tweak(v, p=.1, d=None):
    """Given a vector of initial guesses, return
    vectors with values that are modified by a factor of +/-p
    along with the unmodified values until all possibilities
    are given. d controls number of decimals shown in returned
    values; all are shown when d is None (default).

    EXAMPLES
    ========

    >>> for i in tweak((1,2),.1):
    ...     print(i)
    [1.1, 2.2]
    [1.1, 2]
    [1.1, 1.8]
    [1, 2.2]
    [1, 2]
    [1, 1.8]
    [0.9, 2.2]
    [0.9, 2]
    [0.9, 1.8]
    """"
    from sympy.utilities.iterables import cartes
    if d is None:
        d = 15
    c = []
    for i in v:
        c.append([i*(1+p),i,i*(1-p)])
    for i in cartes(*c):
        yield [round(i,d) for i in i]

eqs = [
    I - E*N + (r[0]*(m[0]*R)**q[0])/(s[0]**q[0]+(m[0]*R)**q[0]) - a[0]*N*R/(b[0] + N),
    a[0]*N*R/(b[0] + N) - m[0]*R - l[0]*R - a[1]*H*R/(b[1] + R),
    a[1]*H*R/(b[1] + R) - m[1]*H - a[1]*H*P/(b[2] + H),
    a[1]*H*P/(b[2] + H) - m[2]*P]

saw = set()
vv = 1.5, 0.7, 0.6, 0.1
for v0 in tweak(vv, d=3):
    equilibrium_values = nsolve(eqs, (N, R, H, P), v0)
    ok = round(equilibrium_values[-1], 3)
    if ok not in saw:
        saw.add(ok)
        print('guess N,R,H,P=',v0,ok)
```

which gives

```
guess N,R,H,P= [1.65, 0.77, 0.66, 0.11] 0.130
guess N,R,H,P= [1.65, 0.77, 0.6, 0.1] 0.0
```