# How to avoid negative solutions from sympy.solve?

Tags: python, sympy

I am having the very same problem [asked in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50476889/how-to-eliminate-negative-solutions-from-sympy-solve-result), but I can't figure out why the solution is not working.

In that question, there was an issue in `sqrt` function that seems to be solved, and now that problem leads to only positive results.

But in my problem, I can't eliminate the negative solution in the following code:

```
import sympy
v,Vs,Vp = sympy.symbols('v,Vs,Vp',real=True,positive=True)
sympy.solve( v - (Vp**2-2*Vs**2)/(2*(Vp**2-Vs**2)),  Vs)
```

Which gives me the result

```
[-sqrt(2)*Vp*sqrt((2*v - 1)/(v - 1))/2, sqrt(2)*Vp*sqrt((2*v - 1)/(v - 1))/2]
```

How can I get only the positive result? What am I missing?

Comment: The response says that anything can be included; thus, you would have to manually filter them out. Have you tried it yet?

Comment: Yes but, as I said above, the response in that question opened an issue in sympy's github (in sqrt function) that seems to be solved. Today, if you try that command you won't get negative values anymore, not needing to filter the results. But in my problem that doesn't happen.

Comment: The difference between that question and this one is that your solution has `v - 1` in the denominator so the solution is not known to be real or complex (i.e. what if `v=1`?). The positive solution might not be positive e.g. if `v = 0.75` it is imaginary. If you know that `v > 1` then you can use a substitution `v -> 1 + u` where `u` is declared positive.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin, thanks! Actually I know that `0<v<0.5`. Is there a way to make this assumption on the `symbols` function?

Comment: There isn't a good way to assume inequalities in the assumptions system but for your case `v -> Rational(1, 2) - u` will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments in the thread already describe, it is not really possible to get what you want in general.

There is a trick to assume `0 < v < 1/2`. Since this involves a few fractions, intuition says that we should probably make a substitution that involves a fraction too.

```py
import sympy
Vs,Vp = sympy.symbols('Vs,Vp', positive=True)
# A hack to assume 0 < v < 1/2
u = sympy.symbols('u', positive=True)
v = 1/(u+2)  # Alternatives like atan can be used when there are trig functions
sol = sympy.solve( v - (Vp**2-2*Vs**2)/(2*(Vp**2-Vs**2)),  Vs)
print(sol)

# Substitute back by redefining v
v = sympy.symbols('v', positive=True)
new_sol = [subsol.subs(u, 1/v - 2).simplify() for subsol in sol]
print(new_sol)
```

The next best you can do in this case is assume all square roots are positive which is a very brave assumption.

```py
import sympy
v,Vs,Vp = sympy.symbols('v,Vs,Vp', real=True, positive=True)
sol = sympy.solve( v - (Vp**2-2*Vs**2)/(2*(Vp**2-Vs**2)),  Vs)
# Assume sqrts are positive and sol is an array
# Both of these are not true in general
# It does not work if we assume the square root can be zero
# Or even complex or negative
s = sympy.symbols('s', positive=True)  # Represents any square root
w = sympy.Wild('w')  # Represents any argument inside a square root
new_sol = [subsol for subsol in sol if subsol.replace(sympy.sqrt(w), s) > 0]
print(new_sol)
```

Both code blocks assume `sol` is an array which is not true in general when it comes to `solve`.